# PRISM 7 log4net integration

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, log4net, prism-7

In the previous PRISM version, one could create a custom Log4Net adapter class (derived from `ILoggerFacade`) and override the protected `CreateLogger` method of the abstract `Prism.Bootstrapper` class like the following:

```
protected override ILoggerFacade CreateLogger()
{
    return new Log4NetAdapter();
}
```

In the newer PRISM 7 version, all methods of the `Bootstrapper` class were moved to the `PrismApplicationBase` class. However, the virtual `CreateLogger` method cannot be found anymore.

**Question:** How can PRISM 7 be configured to use a custom Log4Net adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CreateLogger` method does not exist anymore in Prism 7. You can just register your custom logger as `ILoggerFacade` in the container by overriding `RegisterTypes` in your `PrismApplication`.

```
protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
{
   containerRegistry.RegisterSingleton<ILoggerFacade, CustomLogger>();
}
```

If you already have created an instance of your logger before, you can register it like this.

```
containerRegistry.RegisterInstance(logger);
```